# How to get data with filters from webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to get data from this [site](https://bankrot.gov.by/Debtors/DebtorsList) with unp field filter. I think I need to make post request with data or use any library for substitution of data in the field and activation of the filter by pressing a button.

Tell me what is better to use and which way to go.

I am trying to make post request (Python 3.6):

```
import requests
import json

filters = {
    'DateFrom': 'null',
    'DateTo': 'null',
    'DebtorCategoryId': '0',
    'DeclarantId': '0',
    'FileNumber': '',
    'FileStatusId': "-1",
    'Manager': '',
    'Name': '',
    'ProcedureId': '0',
    'RegionId': '0',
    'Unp': 191409200,
}

payload = {
    'Page': 1,
    'PageSize': 50,
    'SortBy': 'DateStart',
    'SortOrder': 'DESC',
    'Filters': filters,
}
r = requests.post("https://bankrot.gov.by/Debtors/GetDebtors", data=json.dumps(payload))

print(r.text)
```

but i receive this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   IS_ERSB.Controllers.DebtorsController.GetDebtors(PublicDebtorsPagingViewModel model) in D:\work\dev\is_ersb\IS_ERSB\Controllers\DebtorsController.cs:139
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +126
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.&lt;BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod&gt;b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +138
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive&gt;b__3d() +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass46.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive&gt;b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass46.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive&gt;b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass33.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2b.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__1c() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass21.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +288
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[NullReferenceException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IS_ERSB.Controllers.DebtorsController.GetDebtors(PublicDebtorsPagingViewModel model) in D:\work\dev\is_ersb\IS_ERSB\Controllers\DebtorsController.cs:line 139
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = requests.post("https://bankrot.gov.by/Debtors/GetDebtors", json=payload)
```

use **json** instead of **data**

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I needed.